# Highcharts Polar Chart customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'am having problems with polar chart customization. I would like to move data labels by 45° to the right.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bandedos/Ryctk/) and this is the result I would like to get:
[image: result]

1. Is it possible to do that with Polar Chart (it has to be Polar Chart)?
2. Is this the right way to define label text?

   ```
   var categories = ['These', 'are', 'test', 'data'],
   count = 0;
   /* ... */
       labels: {
           formatter: function () {
               var value = categories[count];

               count++;
               if (count == 5) {
                   count = 0;
               }

               return value;
           }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the behaviour you want is a combination of two things:

- Use [`xAxis.categories`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.categories) instead of `formatter`: this is easier than creating a custom formatter. *You can omit this step if you like depending on where you want the gridlines to be drawn.*
- In your `series` options, set [`pointPlacement`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.pointPlacement) to `between`: By default, points will be placed facing 'North' by default, but with this option enabled, they'll be placed inbetween (for a graph with four values, it will put them at 45 degrees).

For example:

```
var categories = ['These', 'are', 'test', 'data'],
count = 0;

$('#container').highcharts({
    // ...        
    xAxis: {
        // ...
        categories: categories,
        // ...
    },
    // ...
    series: [{
        // ...
        pointPlacement: 'between',
        // ...
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know there is a option **startAngle** which gives you ability to manipulate of angle, simply add this option like this:

```
 chart: {
            polar: true
        },
        pane: {
            startAngle: 45,
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts Polar Chart'
        },
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BJqSK/)

[Api](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#pane.startAngle)

Comment: I think he wants to keep the axis line in the same location as his image but just move the text 45 degrees. Such that the label text is in the center of the slice width.